# EditPad RegEx ... I'm lost

Tags: regex, replace, backreference, editpad

I'm trying another find/replace with regex, and I've got some oddball characters that I'm tripping over.

**Summary:**
Some lines *(in this carat separated file)* have a specific tag or two in peren's *(either "(S)" or "(N)")* following the part number, and I need to move it to before the PN.
**Note:** For the lines with both the (S) and the (N), it will always be in that order: (S)(N)

**Subject:**

> ^901A-123^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$28.87^$23.10^--^--^--^--^^
>   ^123B-C45(N)^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$1,224.87^$1,041.10^--^--^--^--^^
>   ^333-11(S)(N)^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$510.67^$459.50^$382.90^2^$357.40^4^^
>   ^333-987M-88(S)^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$608.77^$547.90^$456.50^2^$426.10^4^^

**What I've Tried:**
I started out trying stuff like `^(.+)\(N\)^` and `^([A-Za-z0-9]+)\(N\)^`, but soon started to wonder whether the ^(carat) was complicating things so I *tried* escaping it.
That didn't seem to make a difference :)
So next I tried changing all the carats to pipes:

> |901A-123|DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF|$28.87|$23.10|--|--|--|--||
>   |123B-C45(N)|DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF|$1,224.87|$1,041.10|--|--|--|--||
>   |333-11(S)(N)|DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF|$510.67|$459.50|$382.90|2|$357.40|4||
>   |333-987M-88(S)|DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF|$608.77|$547.90|$456.50|2|$426.10|4||

... and searching with `|([A-Za-z0-9]+)\(N\)|`, and now I'm getting ... wait for it ..... 
*nothing* :)

**Goal:**
While right now I'd be happy with the small victory of figuring out the Find, the ultimate goal is a Replace with a backreference (of the PN).
The goal is to make the subject look like this:

> ^901A-123^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$28.87^$23.10^--^--^--^--^^
>   (N)^123B-C45^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$1,224.87^$1,041.10^--^--^--^--^^
>   (S)(N)^333-11^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$510.67^$459.50^$382.90^2^$357.40^4^^
>   (S)^333-987M-88^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$608.77^$547.90^$456.50^2^$426.10^4^^

Any and all pointers/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you are fighting with special characters: `^`, `()`, `|`.
You need to escape all of them. So you can use this regex (see it [in action](http://regexr.com?33kg8)):

```
\^([^\^]+?)(\(S\))?(\(N\))?(\^.*)
```

and replace with this:

```
$2$3^$1$4
```

I assumed that you have `(S)` and `(N)` only after first tag. Output looks like this:

```
^901A-123^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$28.87^$23.10^--^--^--^--^^
(N)^123B-C45^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$1,224.87^$1,041.10^--^--^--^--^^
(S)(N)^333-11^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$510.67^$459.50^$382.90^2^$357.40^4^^
(S)^333-987M-88^DESC,OF,PROD,AND,STUFF^$608.77^$547.90^$456.50^2^$426.10^4^^
```

### Explanation

Regex:

```
\^               #            match '^' character
([^\^]+?)        # group 1  : match any char other than '^' one or more times, non-greedy
(\(S\))?(\(N\))? # group 2-3: match "(S)" and/or "(N)" or none of them
(\^.*)           # group 4  : match '^' and then everything
```

Replacement:

```
$2$3^$1$4        # concatenate group 2, then 3 and 1 and 4 after a '^' character
```

Answer (score 1):

- `^` and `|` both are metacharacters that need to be escaped.
- Your character class `[A-Za-z0-9]+` doesn't include the dash.

So, try this: Search for

```
(\^[A-Za-z0-9-]+)((?:\(S\))?(?:\(N\))?)
```

and replace with

```
\2\1
```

Comment: I'd search for `^(\^[^^]*)((?:\(S\))?(?:\(N\))?)`.

Comment: @melpomene: And how are you going to separate out the `(N)` and `(S)`? Also, being more explicit about what's allowed to match is better, in my opinion. Whether that includes the start-of-line anchor depends on the OP's needs.

Comment: @mOrloff: What do you mean? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Some of the "false positives" are `^DESC`, `^--`, `^2`, and `^4`.

Comment: Right, these are matched (but are not changed by the replace operation). If you can guarantee that "correct" matches only occur at the start of a line, just add `^` at the very start of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Search for:

```
^(.*?)(\((S\)\(N|S|N)\))(.*?)$
```

Replace with:

```
$2$1$4
```

Since I anchored the pattern with `^` and `$`, you have to apply this regex on each line separately or to use the multiline flag.

Here is a [working demo](http://regexr.com?33kgh).

Comment: This works GREAT, and I *prefer* this syntax (easier for me to figure out) ... mmdemirbas' working answer just came in a hair earlier, so I had to give it to him.

Comment: As you wish, first come first served ;)